# Swift: UIImage orientation problem when applying filter in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uiimageorientation

I want to convert an image to grayscale by **CIPhotoEffectNoir**, but after using it, the image rotates. I searched a lot but the answers can not solve my problem.

This is my code:

```
    func grayscale(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir") {
            filter.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            
            if let output = filter.outputImage {
                if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
                    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your new UIImage instance, don't forget to use the `scale` and `orientaion` values from the original UIImage.

```
return UIImage(
  cgImage: cgimg, 
  scale: image.scale, 
  orientation: image.imageOrientation)
```